# Do European train bookings include reserved seats on a specific train departure?

Tags: trains, europe, bookings

Just recently I booked train tickets for a trip between European cities online. I have traveled by train in Europe before but had never bought tickets online.

After doing a search for trains between stations and selecting a specific train and departure, there was an on-screen confirmation of booking a train from city A to B on train IC xxxxx with departure at HH:MM and arrival at HH:MM. I did this for several trains as I am managing a tight schedule.

After adding all the tickets to cart, checking out and making a payment, I got an email confirming that I bought the intended passages on the chosen train with all the times listed exactly as on the website. So far, this is just what I expected.

The next day I received printed tickets by mail, one for each of the trains that I would be taking *except* that the paper tickets have no time specified, only the departure and arrival city plus a range of validity dates. This makes me doubt that I have a confirmed reservation and that a seat on the trains will be reserved for me:

1. Is it just that the tickets were printed in a generic way?
2. Are there any further steps needed to reserve a seat on a particular train departure?
3. Can the above be completed online or must I do it from a train station in Europe?

**Addendum:**

Based on answers so far, it seems there is much differences between train systems. It is unclear what information is needed to disambiguate but taking the first or my tickets: It is an IC train from Brusels to Luxembourg City. There is a a SNCF logo on the upper corner of the ticket, that could indicate the carrier but it is unclear. The printed ticket seems overly generic which is why I worried enough to ask this question.

Comment: When you booked the tickets was a seat number specified for any or all of them?

Comment: No. There was no seat number nor any screen to allow selecting one.

Comment: The answer may depend on the specific country, train company, and type of service.  Some services do require a separate seat reservation, on others it's optional, and other services may not have reservations at all.  So I think you need to add details to your question.

Comment: All trains are IC followed by 3 or 4 digital number. Not sure if this is the type or the company, they are within and across multiple countries. First segment for example is between Belgium and Luxembourg.

Comment: If you can identify the specific trains, someone should be able to tell you how seat reservations work for that operator, assuming the service does have reserved seats available. You can often book a seat reservation only on the train operator's website, usually for a couple euro.

Comment: @Itai IC means Intercity, typically used for a long-distance service that is neither a suburban/regional service nor a newer high-speed train. The name is used in several countries and the rules will vary.

Comment: Without providing country details it's almost impossible to answer the question. Sometimes even specific destinations might differ. To give you an example in Poland if you book an IC ticket for any trip except between Lodz and Warsaw you'll get your seat assigned unless there are none available. But between Lodz and Warsaw majority of trains give you no seat guarantee and no seat assignment.

Comment: A great idea is you could rent a car instead!

Comment: Btw: Since you bought separate train tickets, any problems caused by missed connections because of delays will probably be your own problem.

Comment: @MartinSchröder no if they were purchased in a single transaction through a single retail vendor. See my answer for details ;-)

Comment: Regarding disambiguation, country would be a good start, as mentioned in several comments. Start with this, it feels a bit counter-productive to go through several rounds of discussion while this information is still missing. If that's not enough, the route or, worse case scenario, the train number would help. The logo on the ticket is less relevant, it depends on where you bought it.

Comment: @MartinSchröder (and @Ister) Actually, in Western Europe at least, the train company *will* generally help you irrespective of the fact you have separate tickets or even of the restrictions included in the EU rules. Simply holding two tickets with a legal connection time is enough in my experience (if they even check that). I have seen the SNCF pay taxis to all stranded travellers for a train arriving after the closure of the metro network in Paris...

Comment: The SNCF logo on the tickets is the company that sold you the tickets, they do not run trains from Belgium into Luxembourg as far as I know. Outside the UK rail tickets do not have to be bought as a single deal for the companies to take care of you when you miss a connection due to one train being late. But on the other hand, they will not help you with overnight stays if your delay makes that needed. (Or at least as far as I have been experiencing.)

Comment: Given that you have a tight schedule, it might make sense to prepare some contingency scenarios (e.g. look up alternative connections in case you're late, even some options where to stay if your'e traveling in the evening). Better than just being left at the mercy of the railway staff (really depends on country and who you run into... from experience Switzerland awesome, Germany great, France generally bad, CZ I just figure it out myself).

Comment: @DanMašek How much experience is that based on? I have never been left stranded in France, I have seen taxis being dispatched, hotels vouchers and more. Germany has usually been worse for me.

Comment: @Relaxed I guess things have changed, it's been a while. Still, I find it better to be prepared.

Comment: Maybe it is just a europa price reduced ticket and then you should have a separate ticket with seats reservations (I think this could be likely as I took this specific train (Brussel-Luxembourg) several times). Anyway, the train gets quite quickly empty when going further away from Bruxelles.

Comment: Well, If you want a full, detailed answer it would be best if you listed your route plan including the train numbers you plan to use. For example on the Brussels-Luxembourg leg you can (for example) pick a 12:33 train that has number IC 2112 but you may pick earlier train (IC 2111 for example) or a later one. It will help recognise specific carriers and rules that apply for them.

Comment: @Ister - Yes, that might help a case but I do have 8 trains and I don't want to have to ask for each one and future ones too. What I prefer is if answers explain how to figure it out and that would serve many more people.

Comment: That's understandable. I've added some extra information including how to find it and what to look for based on your specific train. Details might vary from carrier to carrier and even from train to train but the general idea remains the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As already pointed out in multiple comments this is **very country specific** and based on your description I cannot tell to which country do you travel. I can only rule out few.

Yet since you have received your (printed) tickets it means you are eligible to take a trip as long as you go according to the validity dates and destinations on the ticket. Since your tickets do not have specific time schedule, just validity dates and destinations most probably you are eligible to take *any* train in that range and most probably there is *no seat reservation* available for the trains you have selected. It might be that there is a seat reservation but it is optional and paid additionally.

While very unlikely, sometimes the rules for tickets sold abroad are different than tickets sold locally and your situation might be that you do not get a specific seat reservation despite regular country tickets have them. In such case you get trip flexibility at the cost that there might be no seat available for you. Usually it will mean you'll have to stand part of entire trip if no free seats are available. There are some trains (like EIP in Poland and possibly some other high speed trains across Europe) where you will not be allowed without seat reservation, but I expect for those trains you would get ticket with seat assignment included.

So in general, as long as you have tickets and their validity meets your needs, you're good to go with trains of your choice, possibly with some additional flexibility.

You mentioned your schedule is quite tight so your other concern might be delays. Here the situation is a bit trickier. There is an EU law that gives a passenger a number of rights (all listed [here](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/rail/index_en.htm)). Some of them include:

> - be transported to your final destination at the earliest opportunity (or a later date of your choosing). This includes alternative transport when the train is blocked and the service is suspended.
> - meals and refreshments (proportionate to the waiting time)
> - accommodation – if you have to stay overnight.

Specific local implementation vary in EU member countries, for example in Poland law enforces train operators to ensure that in case of a delay you can continue your travel on the same day. So if your next connection is the last day to the destination on that day this next connection has to wait regardless how long the delay is. If the next connection isn't the last train to the destination on that day it's on railroad company discretion to decide what to do (in some countries it might vary and rules might be more strict for the railroad enforcing it to delay next connection anyway). It might be different in other countries and, as pointed out by Willeke sometimes you just get money for a taxi to your destination.

Anyway in such case it is good to check with the train crew if the next train can also be delayed allowing you to change.

I don't know about other countries but for instance in Poland you are entitled to rebook your ticket for a different schedule (within some timeframe, but it's something like 30 days if I recall correctly) at no cost.

Also since you bought all your tickets from a single travel agent (webpage) and as I understand in one transaction these [rights for package travel](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/holidays/package-travel/index_en.htm) also apply to you (unless all tickets are on the same day):

> The organiser is responsible for the proper performance of all travel services included in your package.
>
> If a travel service can't be provided as agreed, for example if a provider can't carry out an agreed service or can't do so in the agreed form (such as providing transport to or from your destination, providing the agreed type of accommodation, or carrying out a guided tour that you booked), the organiser has to resolve the problem at no extra cost to you.
>
> If it is impossible to make alternative arrangements or you reject the arrangements offered to you on valid grounds, and the package includes your transport (such as air travel), the organiser must offer to repatriate you. If the travel services do not reach the agreed standards and this cannot be resolved on the spot, you may also be entitled to compensation.

You are also protected if for whatever reasons you cannot perform your trip due to the incorrectly issued tickets (on the same page):

> When you book a holiday, the responsible trader (the travel agent or online travel agency) is liable if any of the following occurs during the booking process:
>
> - errors made by the retailer if they are responsible for arranging the booking of a package or of travel services which are part of linked travel arrangements

The page does not state details about the liability.

Note that those last two excerpts state the liability of the ticket retailer, so the webpage where you booked your tickets. As you can see you're double-protected, at least that someone will either have to take you to your final destination (either train company or ticket retailer). Note that the liability (especially in case of tight schedule) is limited to reaching destination only (so it might be you'll be rerouted and miss some of the intermediary targets) and there might be rules limiting the liability if you left yourself inadequate time for a change.

Please note - all those rules apply in EU. **Not all European countries are members of EU!** Yet majority is and you can easily check that. Also country might decide not to apply those rules for local connections but since you're referring to IC tickets that's probably also not the case.

---

Edit based on the specific trip leg provided by OP and some extra research

I couldn't find details about operator that operates the Brussels - Luxembourg trip but I've checked conditions on various sites ([SNCF](https://www.sncf.com/sncv1/en/passengers), [SNCB](https://www.b-europe.com/EN), [RailEurope](https://www.raileurope.com/city/luxembourg)). Each of those pages gives you specific details about fare for each train. For this specific train the fare is open, meaning you can choose any train within the given range of dates. Also on this route there is no seat reservation offered, which means in general you're free to choose any seat available (within your class of course) and once seated you cannot be requested to leave your seat by someone claiming to have seat reservation (unless you pick a special seat that in general is reserved for pregnant women, mother with children or people with some disabilities - check the stickers over the seats that informs about that and I suggest - avoid those seats). Moreover Rail Europe claims the ticket is valid for 15 days, giving you a huuuge flexibility:

> **From BRUXELLES NORD BR To LUXEMBOURG LUX**
>
> **Eurocities  2106 - Reservation not included**
>
> **1 x Ind. Open Ticket Adult**
>
> European open ticket must be used within the 15 days validity period. Journey might be effected on any date within the period of validity. Open Tickets do not guarantee a seat, thus reservations are highly recommended. Important: *Reservations are mandatory on most of high speed, scenic trains and all night trains.*

The scripted highlight is mine.

Also the same train checked on SNCB page (that is IMO most accurate for this particular leg - I believe this is the actual operator of this specific train, but it's just a best guess based on my knowledge of regional transport) shows those conditions (to obtain it simply use the trip planner and follow with the ticket purchase up until you have a specific train selected):

> Bruxelles-Midi/Brussel-Zuid - Luxembourg € 43.60
>
> Adult (26-59): 1 € 43.60 per person
>
> **Flex Fare Adult 2nd Class**
>
> **Special information:** *Ticket valid for any conventional train on the requested route during the whole validity period of the ticket* (for homeprinted tickets, the validity period is limited to the requested travel date). Not valid on high-speed trains, except for ICE trains.
>
> **Refund Conditions:** Refund possible for tickets presented up to the first day of validity. After the first day of validity, non refundable.
>
> **Exchange Conditions:** No exchange possible
>
> **Travel Conditions:** no specific travel conditions. ATTENTION: homeprint tickets have a validity of 1 day!

Again, scripted highlight is mine.

On this [SNCB page about passenger rights](https://www.b-europe.com/EN/Legal/Passenger-Rights) you can read more about carrier specific implementation of those rights described earlier. I'll not quote it here, as this will lead you to the most up-to-date terms and in case of any changes in the future the quote might become misleading.

Finally this nice [SNCB page about terms and conditions](https://www.b-europe.com/EN/Legal/Conditions-of-Carriage) provides links to many carriers T&C details that should provide final, definite information if you're still in doubt. I just need to warn you, that it's sometimes not so obvious to find out which specific fare conditions apply and some of the pages are available in the carrier language only.

One last remark - it is often possible to buy a ticked without seat reservation for a train with either optional or mandatory seat reservation. In most cases (from my experience all trains other than high-speed and some express class, definitely all the standard ones that will be marked just with IC in the train number) such ticket is enough to have a trip and usually it gives you a possibility to obtain a seat reservation (for free if it is compulsory for a one-trip tickets bought directly at the carrier, paid if the reservation is optional or mandatory but paid additionally - not sure if this option is still used anywhere but yes, there was something like that in the past). The channel to obtain such seat reservation depends on your ticket and a carrier, in general you should be good to get it any any counter selling the tickets of that carrier, and for sure in the country of the operator.

If the seat reservation is not possible with a regular fare for that route you'll not be able to get it in any way for other than standard tickets as well.

If for some specific leg you're still unsure or can't find the details as I show here, try calling the carrier in the country of train departure. They will for sure be able to give you most accurate details given you provide the train number you plan to go with.

Comment: I have never heard that 'rule' that the last train on the day has to wait for late passengers. Most train companies I know read it as having to transport the passengers to the needed destination if the last train of the day misses the connection, they often do that by paying for a taxi. For trains earlier in the day, they just point out the alternative travel options, (which may make you miss a connection farther on but that is not their problem.)

Comment: OK, in Poland the rule says specifically that the last train waits if there are changing passengers on delayed trains that will miss the train due to the delay.. The country specific implementations may vary though and the general rule indeed is to ensure transport - it might be by other means, like giving money for taxi or some other means if it still exists. If the transport is overnight, an accommodation is also required. I'll change the answer accordingly.

Comment: *"...and probably all high speed trains across Europe) where you will not be allowed without seat reservation"* - the German ICE high speed trains do not require seat reservation at all if you buy a regular DB ticket. So "probably all" is certainly wrong :-)

Comment: @Willeke thanks for pointing out. Fixed. I do use the edit reason field, just thought not everyone checks that.

Comment: (+1) I believe there are older, UIC rules about this. And I have seen train companies help travellers with connections on entirely separate tickets (i.e. not covered by EU rights), pay taxis or hotels long before the EU got involved so it always pays to ask and the guarantees are often wider than suspected.

Comment: @Relaxed certainly a reasonable company of any kind will support their client when there is a harm done by them. And delay can definitely cause harm so reasonable railroad company will offer as much assistance as possible. Also next to the law requiring it for the last train the companies also often implement trains synchronisation and by default delay one train if an earlier one that often carry people to change is delayed. Also sometimes they are willing to slightly delay departure even if there is nothing like that. That's why it's always good to inform the train crew about planned change.

Comment: On top of that there is also tort law that sometimes also applies. I've been in a situation, where a local train was delayed almost 2 hours. I was going to catch a plane with it and took all safety measures including taking the earliest possible train with almost 2h spare time. But all signs showed that the train is going to be delayed even further. As a result I decided to leave the train about 25 km prior to my destination and take taxi to the airport from there. Even though they weren't very willing to do so, the railroad company reimbursed the taxi cost (~40 EUR, way above ticket price)

Comment: @Ister Trains companies sometimes delay the last train of the day but otherwise try to avoid it as it can create a lot of cascading disruptions on the network. I once read it was more common in Germany and a reason why they had a rather poor punctuality record but it's certainly not the default everywhere.

Comment: @Relaxed Well, for sure it does happen in Poland. There might be circumstances giving some space for that. It's not something to really count on, but giving it a try costs nothing anyway and sometimes might work.

Answer (score 17):

It really depends on the country/train, IC is a code used in different countries for long-distance non-high-speed trains with slightly different rules. Generally speaking, those trains have either no seat reservations or optional seat reservations (but no mandatory seat reservations).

Therefore I would assume you do have a ticket that's valid on your chosen trains. In some cases, seat reservations are available but not mandatory and open tickets do not mention the train for that reason. For the one specific route you mentioned, seat reservations are simply not available on IC trains at all. If you're really concerned about finding a seat, you could book a first class ticket. It doesn't guarantee anything either but there is usually more space in first class.

Where available, it is certainly possible to book a seat reservation separately but that's usually not possible online (the German railways do sell them online).

Comment: For what it's worth, in Finland (regarding IC-trains) the convention seems to be/(seems to be shifting towards) that you sit wherever you want (with or without seat reservation) and give your seat back in case someone with reservation asks for it. (This is especially true in non-full trains, and this seems to be a fairly new phenomenon)

Comment: "that's usually not possible online" - For me it was possible in Poland, Germany and Netherlands, that is, in every country I tried to do it.Are you sure about "usually not"?

Comment: @Mołot Possible in The Netherlands? Are you sure? Dutch trains don't have seat reservations. What train was this?

Comment: @gerrit international one. Maybe that's why.

Comment: @DavidRicherby "Usually not" is probably about right for being able to reserve a seat online without simultaneously buying a ticket. I don't know about French, but British trains won't normally let you reserve seats online separately from buying a ticket - you can, however, get one from a ticket office (or online at the same time as buying the ticket).

Comment: that seems bizarre and socially awkward, @ChristianW. !  thanks for the report!

Comment: @Fattie Why do you think so? It’s the norm in most of Europe (definitely everywhere I’ve travelled by train). *Sometimes* reserved seats are marked but even then people are free to sit in them on free stretches, and will vacate them in case the reservation holder arrives.

Comment: hi @KonradRudolph !  Hmm, i travel by train in Europe a lot - I guess I simply .. never noticed this.  Cheers!

Comment: @meta Oops -- I misread and thought that Relaxed was talking about getting seat reservations online _at all_, rather than just about getting a reservation without getting a ticket, too. Comment deleted.

Comment: @Mołot in Polad your IC ticket has a complimentary seat reservation regardless of the purchase channel, unless you travel a train that goes only from Warsaw to Lodz (or vice versa). Note however that if you have some multi-trip ticket (e.g. weekend full coverage or monthly) you can get seat reservation over internet only if you purchased your ticket online as well. Otherwise you'll have to get seat reservation at the counter (the opposite is not true). With Germany my only experience was Warsaw-Berlin express, also with complimentary seat reservation.

Comment: I will speak for Belgium: there is NO reservation possible for a specific train in domestic service. Actually, being seated is considered a bonus by the belgian rail company, you pay for the transport. So there's no way to even complain if you had to stand for the whole journey. Don't want to scare anybody though this situation is far from usual outside of rush hours or special events...

Comment: @ChristianW., you've been travelling on different trains than I have, then... I'm not even sure how to book a regular long-distance train ticket from VR in advance without getting a seat reservation with it. Local trains are different, of course, or if you're in the military, or just get the ticket after you board the train, etc.

Comment: @Mołot I already mentioned Germany. I didn't know about Poland and to be honest know generally a lot less about train travel in central or eastern Europe. It does not seem possible in Belgium, France or Switzerland. In the Netherlands, it's not possible to get seat reservation at all on NS IC trains, even at the station. In fact, I have seen Dutch people argue with tourists on the EC train to Berlin because they didn't even understand the concept of seat reservation.

Comment: @ilkkachu and you've never had anyone sit on your seat (that your ticket says)? Pretty lucky, I'd say! I Travelled from Pasila to Tampere weekly for quite a long period and at some point I just gave up even trying to go to my reserved seat, as it was more or less always taken by the time the train got to Pasila from the central railway station.  I ended up just sitting at any free spot. (This is obviously not the case with full trains, as with those people actually tend to use their seats as it's the only option)

Answer (score 6):

From what you said, you can expect that you do **not** have a reservation.

On TGV/Thalys you are (usually) required to have a seat reservation, so whenever you buy a ticket, you kinda automatically have one (otherwise you can't get a ticket). The seat number is printed on the ticket.

On ICE (note the "E") which is the better, faster "express" version of IC with approx. 1/3 as many stops and running at approx. 2x cruise speed, you (usually) get reservation for free and automatically *in first class*, but in second class you do not get it automatically. You have to book it explicitly, and it will cost you some 4-5€ extra, but I would absolutely recommend it because some ICEs are full to the last seat, and nothing sucks more than having to stand, or stay in the restaurant wagon (if there's one) for 4 hours.
I wouldn't know for sure about seat reservations for first class in IC (without "E"), the tree or four times I've travelled IC in my life, it was 2nd class, and seat reservation was (of course) extra.

In any case, the wagon and seat number is printed on the ticket if you have a reservation (if there's none, you don't have one).

Further steps to take would be to reserve a seat, which can be done online. Note that depending on what country you do it in, and depending on what alternative carriers are involved, it can be adventurous (for example, two years ago I learned that booking with Bahn and going to Italy would much to my surprise work just fine with the Italians, but the Austrians would give me trouble for the short segment in between. Same physical train, different carrier. Hey, if anything, you'd think it wouldn't work on the Italian end, but that was actually no issue at all.).

It is generally possible to buy tickets without seat, and funnily enough to reserve seats without a ticket. This seems nonsensical, but since there are tickets that are valid on several days (virtually unlimited, even) and subscriptions that allow 100% free of charge travel in at least some countries, this actually makes sense. Those people having e.g. one of the 100% reduced fare subscriptions would just book a seat when they wish to travel.

About "tight schedule", I'd like to warn you. This is not the best possible approach in combination with "train", in particular IC. There's countries which are arguably somewhat better, and some which are definitively not among the better ones, and it's not always obvious. IC *per se* is on the more unreliable side due to having many stops and being a lower-priority train. If you have a tight schedule, ICE/TGV may be a better choice (although I've had a 2 hours delay on a 3 hour trip on German ICE already, too).
You mentioned Belgium-Luxemburg being the first segment. My personal experience with Belgium is that you stand at the station and no train is to be seen. As you get more and more nervous and ask staff about it, they'll say "Yeah sure, that train leaves in 2 minutes. But not today.". When you ask when the next train will leave, they'll tell you: "Tomorrow morning at 6:14". Yup, Brussels, capital of Europe.

So... tight schedule *may* work, but it may not be the best plan.

Comment: One positive about the tickets without compulsory seat reservation is that they are usually valid for all trains on that day or even for a longer period of time. So you can catch any train on that route on the day or within the range of dates given on the ticket. And sometimes also alternative routes are accepted.

Comment: ICE is the German equivalent of TGV, not just a "better IC".

Comment: This is country specific so referring to specific countries would be a good idea. In Poland majority of IC trains have compulsory seat reservation.

Comment: @jwenting: Well, no, not really. Although the ICE does look fancier and more stream-liney, TGV is a wholly different class of train. TGV is more like 350km/h whereas ICE is 200km/h if you are lucky (often rather like 150km/h). TGV is like Paris-Nantes in 2 hours whereas ICE is Frankfurt-Munich, which is 30-40km less distance, in 3 1/2 hours. IC differs from ICE _mostly_ in being less fancy trains, and having more stops (and also, being slightly slower, but not that much really).

Comment: @Damon Not true: E.g. Mannheim Hbf - Paris Est TGV and ICE are used interchangeably, both clocking in at 3 h 10.

Comment: @Damon I did 268km/h on an ICE last Sunday, but that is besides the point. ICE are German high(est) speed trains, while TGV are French high speed trains. The IC name is used in many European countries to denote a variety of services.

Comment: @Damon is right. TGV is not the train alone but also the dedicated high-speed line it takes. It's the line that allows TGVs to sustain the speed that high for that long. ICEs travel on regular routes that were upgraded but are still shared with other kinds of trains. Dedicated ICE lines are few and short, that's why ICE sets can reach their full potential only in France. TGVs take LGVs that were built just for them, and use older infrastructure only for connecting to city centers. Shinkansen is the equivalent to TGV in this regard, intra-German ICE is merely "the next best thing".

Comment: @Marianne013 Damon has a point, there are precious few real high speed line in Germany (Frankfurt-Cologne was opened to much fanfare a decade after similar speeds were reached in France, Spain, or Japan) and parallel services on *French* high-speed lines. ICE are gorgeous trains and I love them but they are a lot more similar to regular IC trains both in technical terms and in their concept of operations.

Comment: TGV [also operates](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_lignes_%C3%A0_grande_vitesse_en_France#/media/File:Carte_TGV.svg) on a fairly large number of non-highspeed tracks.

Comment: @DanMašek Only incidentally, either to extend the network (so-called province-province destinations and secondary destinations) or to save costs (the LGV Atlantique and the LGV Est were initially just long enough to reach the main destination, Rennes, Nantes or Strasbourg in under three hours). From the very beginnings in the 1980s, the network is centered on high-speed lines allowing 300 kph, that's what these trains are for. That's not the case at all with ICE.

Comment: In Germany you frequently (outside rush hours of course) get away with taking an occupied seat, even one at a table (which are rare in mainstay railcars). Occasionally you have to change seats when the passenger with a legitimate reservation shows up. Hint: Always have them show you their reservation. Some are bold enough just to claim to have one, others only look for the seat number but disregard the railcar number. If you want to work during the journey, however, spend the reservation fee - it sucks to wrap up equipment half an hour into the trip ...

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for the IC from Brussels to Luxembourg City. This is the IC 21xx (with xx a sequence number for the nth train of the day starting at 04 for that train line). You can look up the exact schedule on the [Belgian railway website](http://www.belgianrail.be/jp/nmbs-realtime/query.exe/en?HWAI=VIEW!view=realtimeinfo) (select the train radiobutton and enter your train line, f.e. IC2110). Date is optional, but recommended as some trains have different schedules in weekends and on holidays.

This is a standard Belgian IC train and does not have seat reservation or specific time requirements. Your ticket is very likely counted as a [standard ticket](https://www.belgiantrain.be/en/tickets-and-railcards/standard-ticket/) (not 100% because booked through SNCF and not SNCB). The general conditions for this type of ticket are: valid on the date (you can get on any train that day) printed on the ticket and you are allowed to get off at any stop on that line and get on a later train on the same line (this is a recent change in conditions). So you can visit any cities in between, should you want to. You can find the conditions at the bottom of the page I linked to for standard ticket, but they are only available in french and dutch.

Optional information:
For future reference, when travelling through Belgium, it can be more interesting financially to use several tickets with linked destinations to reduce your travel costs. In this case, I would have suggested to take a ticket from Brussels to Arlon (Arlon being the last stop in Belgium) and a ticket from Arlon to Luxembourg. This comes out slightly cheaper in general (few euros usually). However, if you are under 26 or travel frequently in Belgium, you can take advantages of significantly cheaper rides using [GoPass 1 or GoPass 10 (under 26)](https://www.belgiantrain.be/en/tickets-and-railcards/overview-products/young-child) or [RailPass (over 26, at least 10 trips)](https://www.belgiantrain.be/en/tickets-and-railcards/overview-products/adult-senior). Return trips are also cheaper in the weekend (if the return happens in the same weekend).

Answer (score -7):

I know Dutch and British trains (with some exceptions, like ICE, TGV, and some other international trains) have no reserved seats anywhere.
I think it's the same in Belgium, Germany, and probably elsewhere from what I've seen of their train services (which isn't all that much, thank god, I hate trains in general).

Certainly on Dutch trains (again, ICE and TGV excepted, as well as international trains BUT only for the international segment of the trip) you don't buy a ticket for a specific train either, but for a specific day (or even a ticket without a date). Again, in my experience elsewhere it's pretty much the same there. E.g. I've traveled by train in the UK and just as in the Netherlands the ticket just states the city pairs and the date(s) on which the ticket is valid.

In this way European trains are much more like a bus service than an airline service, and the service level available to passengers reflects this with usually no catering, very limited if any toilets, and regular overcrowding.

Comment: Most medium-to-long-distance British trains do offer seat reservations. They are typically free, but optional, and apply to a particular train even if the accompanying ticket is valid on several services. For this reason, the seat reservation is generally printed on a separate slip from the ticket itself. Local lines, including metro services and commuter trains run by, for example, Northern Rail, however, tend not to offer this.

Comment: By your own admission, you haven't seen much of train services.  Your limited experience  is causing you to overgeneralize.

Comment: @georgewatson For some tickets (e.g. "Advanced" tickets), which are only _valid_ for specific trains at specific times, reservations are essential (but are also an integral part of booking the ticket). Although, as you say, they are generally printed on a separate ticket.

Comment: That seems to be based entirely on your experience in the Benelux. It isn't true of many places in the world and specifically isn't generally true in Germany or the UK, you need to edit or delete this answer.